# CI + Test: run unit tests against DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, continuous-integration, circleci

Executing tests against mongo DB on the CI (circleCI) fails even though they pass locally.

Am installing mongo db and connect the app to the db, here is my circle.yml file

```
machine:
  node:
    version: 7.2.1 
dependencies:
  override:
    - sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
    - sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
    - echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu precise/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
    - sudo apt-get update
    - sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
    - sudo service mongod restart
    - npm install
test:
  override:
    - npm run test
```

The DataBase URL: `mongodb://mongodb:27017/db-name`

Answer (score 0):

## CircleCI already provides MongoDB 3.0.7 by default

Edit your circle.yml for this:

```
machine:
  node:
    version: 7.2.1 
dependencies:
  override:
    - npm install
test:
  override:
    - npm run test
```

[More information](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/build-image-trusty/)

Comment: I think CircleCi provide mongodb 2.x, anyway i give your solution a try and seems not able to connect to DB
 ```Uncaught MongoError: failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb mongodb:27017]```